# How do I implement IEnumerable in my Dictionary wrapper class that implements IEnumerable<Foo>?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm trying to create a wrapper for a `Dictionary<String,Foo>`.

`Dictionary<String,Foo>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String,Foo>>`, but I want my wrapper class to implement `IEnumerable<Foo>`.  So I tried this:

```
public class FooCollection : IEnumerable<Foo>
{
    private Dictionary<string, Foo> fooDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Foo>();

    public IEnumerator<Foo> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return fooDictionary.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    // Other wrapper methods omitted

}
```

However I get this error:

> 'FooCollection' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'.  'FooCollection.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'.

However I don't understand this error, because `FooCollection.GetEnumerator()` returns an `IEnumerator<Foo>`, and `IEnumerator<Foo>` is an `IEnumerator`.

EDIT:

The solution of explicitly implementing `IEnumerator.GetEnumerator()` works.  However I'm now wondering why when I "Go to definition" on a `List<T>` I see only one definition of GetEnumerator:
`public List<T>.Enumerator GetEnumerator();`

Apparently `List<T>` can have a single `GetEnumerator` method that returns something that implements both `IEnumerator<T>` and `IEnumerator`, but I have to have one method for each?

EDIT:

As answered by LukeH below, `List<T>` *does* include the explicit interface implementations.  Apparently Visual Studio just doesn't list those when generating method stubs from the metadata. (See this previous question: [Why does the VS Metadata view does not display explicit interface implemented members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268632/why-does-the-vs-metadata-view-does-not-display-explicit-interface-implemented-mem) )

Before posting this question I had tried checking `List<T>` (via "Go to Definition" in Visual Studio) to see if I needed to implement multiple versions of GetEnumerator. I guess this wasn't the most reliable way to check.

Anyway, I'm marking this as answered. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to implement `IEnumerator.GetEnumerator()` as well

Comment: `IEnumerator<Foo>` != `IEnumerator`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following explicit interface implementation:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Although `IEnumerator<T>` is an `IEnumerator`, the contract for `IEnumerable` returns an `IEnumerator` specifically, not an `IEnumerator<T>`

Comment: LOL looks like he has his answer 4 ways.

Comment: This works.  But then how come List<T> only appears to implement GetEnumerator one way? (Based on the metadata anyway, I just see `public List<T>.Enumerator GetEnumerator();`)  I figured if `List<T>` only had to implement it once, the same would be true for me.

Comment: @TimGoodman `List<T>` implements the `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces explicitly, and has one public method (which is the one that you see).

Answer (score 8):

When implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, you must also explicitly implement `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`. The method for the generic interface is not valid in and of itself as an implementation for the non-generic method contract. You can have one call the other, or since you have a child object whose enumerator you are using, just copy/paste;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class FooCollection : IEnumerable<Foo>
{
    private Dictionary<string, Foo> fooDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Foo>();

    public IEnumerator<Foo> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return fooDictionary.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        //forces use of the non-generic implementation on the Values collection
        return ((IEnumerable)fooDictionary.Values).GetEnumerator();
    }

    // Other wrapper methods omitted

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that there is no such thing as return type covariance in .NET - `IEnumerator M()` and `IEnumerator<Foo> M()` are completely different methods.

The workaround is that you have to implement the non-generic version explicitly:

```
System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    // this calls the IEnumerator<Foo> GetEnumerator method
    // as explicit method implementations aren't used for method resolution in C#
    // polymorphism (IEnumerator<T> implements IEnumerator)
    // ensures this is type-safe
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. However, see my edit.  How come `List<T>` apparently doesn't have to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As long as generic [IEnumerable{T}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) inherit [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) You have to implement `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` as well. You can do it explicitly like:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
       return GetEnumerator();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've already had several answers to your main question. I'll answer the question raised in your edit...

The `List<T>` class actually has *three* different `GetEnumerator` methods: The public method that's called when the compile-time instance is typed as `List<T>` itself, and two explicit interface implementations to meet the `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>` contracts. The enumerator objects returned by all three methods are all the same `List<T>.Enumerator` type behind-the-scenes.

```
// Public method
public List<T>.Enumerator GetEnumerator() { /* ... */ }

// IEnumerable<T> explicit interface implementation
IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() { /* ... */ }

// IEnumerable explicit interface implementation
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I hit "Go To Definition" on a List<T> and then search (Ctrl-F) for GetEnumerator, I only see the public method.  Perhaps Visual Studio just doesn't produce an accurate list from the metadata?

Comment: This is maybe a fairly minor quibble on my part, but I actually checked List<T> to see if it implemented multiple GetEnumerator methods posting my original question, so I'm wondering how I was mislead.

Comment: Ah, according to this previous question, when Visual Studio generates method stubs from metadata, it doesn't include explicit interface implementations. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268632/why-does-the-vs-metadata-view-does-not-display-explicit-interface-implemented-mem

Comment: The other answers do not include the need for the <T> for one of the enumerators - namely, IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() - that did the trick for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you implement the generic IEnumerable interface, you also have to implement the non generic IEnumerable interface. The error is about the missing non generic method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the declaration of IEnumerable:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
{
    new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

notice the new keyword.

Here's the declaration of IEnumerable:

```
public interface IEnumerable
{

    IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
}
```

So now you have a GetEnumerator method, but which one of those two are you implementing? Therefore, you need to add an explicit implementation of the non-generic version:

```
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
```