# Why do I need to cast from ConcurrentDictionary to IDictionary in order to use Add()?

Tags: c#, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

If I have a `ConcurrentDictionary` and want to use the `Add()` function, I need to cast to `IDictionary`:

```
var cd = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
cd.Add(1, 1);  // Compile error: does not contain a definition for 'Add'
IDictionary<int, int> id = cd;
id.Add(1, 1);  // Works
```

Question [ConcurrentDictionary and IDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035243/concurrentdictionary-and-idictionary) tells me it's because `ConcurrentDictionary` implements `IDictionary` explicitly, using private methods.

My question: **Why** is `ConcurrentDictionary` implemented like that? What is the benefit of hiding the use of an implemented interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question: Why is ConcurrentDictionary implemented like that?

I believe it's to encourage you to think of the concurrency implications - that multiple threads may be writing the same keys at the same time. Adding an existing key is therefore somewhat less likely to be a programming error, and should be considered carefully.

- If you want to overwrite unconditionally, use the indexer
- If you want to add or update, where the update can use the existing value, use `AddOrUpdate`
- If you want to add if possible, but not overwrite any existing value, use `TryAdd`

If you find yourself wanting the existing `Add` behaviour frequently, you could always write your own extension method.

Comment: It's probably also because `IDictionary.Add` is simply implemented as `if (!TryAdd(...)) throw ...;`, which is so trivial that even in those cases where that makes sense for a concurrent dictionary, the caller still has the option of doing exactly the same thing, without having to resort to accessing the dictionary through `IDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can try using TryAdd() or AddOrUpdate() method from ConcurrentDictionay, as you can see here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx