# ClientBase doesn't implement IDisposable member

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c#-4.0, idisposable

How is it possible for the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase abstract class to implement IDisposable Interface if the Dispose() Method declaration is not visible/declared?

If I try to do the same I get an error and can't compile

```
abstract class ATeste : IDisposable
{
}
```

'ATeste' does not implement interface member 'System.IDisposable.Dispose()'

I'm using VS 2010 and Framework 4.0.

Check the ClientBase declaration:

```
    // Summary:
//     Provides the base implementation used to create Windows Communication Foundation
//     (WCF) client objects that can call services.
//
// Type parameters:
//   TChannel:
//     The channel to be used to connect to the service.
public abstract class ClientBase<TChannel> : ICommunicationObject, IDisposable where TChannel : class
{
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>
    //     class using the default target endpoint from the application configuration
    //     file.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     Either there is no default endpoint information in the configuration file,
    //     more than one endpoint in the file, or no configuration file.
    protected ClientBase();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>
    //     class using the callbackInstance as the callback object in a duplex conversation.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   callbackInstance:
    //     The callback object that the client application uses to listen for messages
    //     from the connected service.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The callback instance is null.
    //
    //   System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     Either there is no default endpoint information in the configuration file,
    //     more than one endpoint in the file, or no configuration file.
    protected ClientBase(InstanceContext callbackInstance);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>
    //     class using the configuration information specified in the application configuration
    //     file by endpointConfigurationName.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   endpointConfigurationName:
    //     The name of the endpoint in the application configuration file.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The specified endpoint information is null.
    //
    //   System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     The endpoint cannot be found or the endpoint contract is not valid.
    protected ClientBase(string endpointConfigurationName);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>
    //     class using the specified binding and target address.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   binding:
    //     The binding with which to make calls to the service.
    //
    //   remoteAddress:
    //     The address of the service endpoint.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The binding is null.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The remote address is null.
    protected ClientBase(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>
    //     class using the specified callback service and endpoint configuration information.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   callbackInstance:
    //     The callback object that the client uses to listen for messages from the
    //     connected service.
    //
    //   endpointConfigurationName:
    //     The name of the endpoint in the application configuration file.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The callback instance is null.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The endpoint is null.
    //
    //   System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     The endpoint cannot be found or the endpoint contract is not valid.
    protected ClientBase(InstanceContext callbackInstance, string endpointConfigurationName);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>
    //     class using the specified target address and endpoint information.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   endpointConfigurationName:
    //     The name of the endpoint in the application configuration file.
    //
    //   remoteAddress:
    //     The address of the service.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The endpoint is null.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The remote address is null.
    //
    //   System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     The endpoint cannot be found or the endpoint contract is not valid.
    protected ClientBase(string endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>
    //     class.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   endpointConfigurationName:
    //     The name of the endpoint in the application configuration file.
    //
    //   remoteAddress:
    //     The address of the service.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The endpoint is null.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The remote address is null.
    //
    //   System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     The endpoint cannot be found or the endpoint contract is not valid.
    protected ClientBase(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>
    //     class.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   callbackInstance:
    //     The callback service.
    //
    //   binding:
    //     The binding with which to call the service.
    //
    //   remoteAddress:
    //     The address of the service endpoint.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The callback instance is null.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The binding is null.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The remote address is null.
    protected ClientBase(InstanceContext callbackInstance, Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>
    //     class.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   callbackInstance:
    //     The callback object that the client uses to listen for messages from the
    //     connected service.
    //
    //   endpointConfigurationName:
    //     The name of the endpoint in the application configuration file.
    //
    //   remoteAddress:
    //     The address of the service.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The callback instance is null.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The endpoint is null.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The remote address is null.
    //
    //   System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     The endpoint cannot be found or the endpoint contract is not valid.
    protected ClientBase(InstanceContext callbackInstance, string endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>
    //     class.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   callbackInstance:
    //     The callback object that the client uses to listen for messages from the
    //     connected service.
    //
    //   endpointConfigurationName:
    //     The name of the endpoint in the application configuration file.
    //
    //   remoteAddress:
    //     The address of the service.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The callback instance is null.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The endpoint is null.
    //
    //   System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     The remote address is null.
    //
    //   System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     The endpoint cannot be found or the endpoint contract is not valid.
    protected ClientBase(InstanceContext callbackInstance, string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress);

    // Summary:
    //     Gets the inner channel used to communicate with the service.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An implementation of the target service contract interface passed as the
    //     type parameter to the constructor.
    protected TChannel Channel { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the underlying System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<TChannel> object.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<TChannel> object.
    public ChannelFactory<TChannel> ChannelFactory { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the client credentials used to call an operation.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     Returns a System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials that represents
    //     the proof of identity presented by the client.
    public ClientCredentials ClientCredentials { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the target endpoint for the service to which the WCF client can connect.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The target endpoint.
    public ServiceEndpoint Endpoint { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the underlying System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel implementation.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The client channel for the WCF client object.
    public IClientChannel InnerChannel { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the current state of the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel> object.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The value of the System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState of the object.
    public CommunicationState State { get; }

    // Summary:
    //     Causes the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel> object to transition
    //     immediately from its current state into the closed state.
    public void Abort();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Causes the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel> object to transition
    //     from its current state into the closed state.
    public void Close();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns a new channel to the service.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A channel of the type of the service contract.
    protected virtual TChannel CreateChannel();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Instructs the inner channel to display a user interface if one is required
    //     to initialize the channel prior to using it.
    public void DisplayInitializationUI();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Replicates the behavior of the default keyword in C#.
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   T:
    //
    // Returns:
    //     Returns null if T is a reference type and zero if T is a numeric value type.
    protected T GetDefaultValueForInitialization<T>();
    protected void InvokeAsync(ClientBase<TChannel>.BeginOperationDelegate beginOperationDelegate, object[] inValues, ClientBase<TChannel>.EndOperationDelegate endOperationDelegate, SendOrPostCallback operationCompletedCallback, object userState);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Causes the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel> object to transition
    //     from the created state into the opened state.
    public void Open();

    // Summary:
    //     A delegate that is used by System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>.InvokeAsync(System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.BeginOperationDelegate,System.Object[],System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.EndOperationDelegate,System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback,System.Object)
    //     for calling asynchronous operations on the client.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   inValues:
    //     The input values to the asynchronous call.
    //
    //   asyncCallback:
    //     Reference to the method to be called when the corresponding asynchronous
    //     operation completes.
    //
    //   state:
    //     An System.Object that lets the client distinguish between different asynchronous
    //     calls. It is made available to the client in the arguments parameter of the
    //     event completion callback.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The result of the asynchronous call.
    protected delegate IAsyncResult BeginOperationDelegate(object[] inValues, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, object state);

    // Summary:
    //     A delegate that is invoked by System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>.InvokeAsync(System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.BeginOperationDelegate,System.Object[],System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.EndOperationDelegate,System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback,System.Object)
    //     on successful completion of the call made by System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>.InvokeAsync(System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.BeginOperationDelegate,System.Object[],System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.EndOperationDelegate,System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback,System.Object)
    //     to System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>.BeginOperationDelegate.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   result:
    //     The result returned by the call made by System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>.InvokeAsync(System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.BeginOperationDelegate,System.Object[],System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.EndOperationDelegate,System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback,System.Object)to
    //     System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>.BeginOperationDelegate.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An array of System.Object that contains the results of the call to the asynchronous
    //     method. The operation may have multiple return values, which are all returned
    //     in this object array.
    protected delegate object[] EndOperationDelegate(IAsyncResult result);

    // Summary:
    //     Stores the results from an asynchronous call made by the client.
    protected class InvokeAsyncCompletedEventArgs : AsyncCompletedEventArgs
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the results from an asynchronous call made by the client.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     An array of System.Object that contains the results from an asynchronous
        //     call made by the client.
        public object[] Results { get; }
    }
}
```

---

I tested again, but this time explicity implementing IDisposable. Now it makes sense

```
abstract class ATest : IDisposable
{
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class Test : ATest
{
}
```

Now, I can't access the Dispose() method when I instantiate the Test Class:

```
        Test t = new Test();
        t.Dispose();
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the code you posted came from, but according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340248.aspx) it implements `IDisposable.Dispose` explicitly

Comment: +1 for someone showing how to implement `Dispose` explicitly in his `ATeste` class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[using explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

`IDisposable` is visible and can be invoked as

```
var client = new WCFTestServiceClient(); // assumingWCFTestServiceClient is WCF client proxy that inherits from ClientBase
(client as IDisposable).Dispose();
```

Comment: I tested it right now. You are right, thanks. And sorry for my noob question.

Answer (score 8):

As pretty much everyone has pointed out, the interface method is explicitly implemented. The source code you are seeing for `ClientBase<TChannel>` is `from Metadata` (see [Metadata as Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms236403%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in Visual Studio). Note the lack of implementation for any function or a `partial` keyword.

Visual Studio will not show explicitly implemented interface members `from Metadata` (see [Stack Overflow question 72686320](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268632/why-does-the-vs-metadata-view-does-not-display-explicit-interface-implemented-me))

---

Edit:

An **explicitly** implemented interface method must be called from the interface directly (this is how it differs from one that was implemented **implicitly**). The correct way to call it is as follows

```
using System;

abstract class ATest : IDisposable
{
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class Test : ATest
{
}

class OtherClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        ((IDisposable)t).Dispose();
    }
}
```

The result is `Unhandled Exception: System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.`

Answer (score 4):

`ClientBase<TChannel>` implements `IDisposable` using [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx).

The implementation for this just calls close:

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    this.Close();
}
```